# Running flake8. Why I'm getting this error. What does threads have to do with it?

Tags: python, multithreading, lint, flake8

Here I'm trying to run flake8 on my project.
`flake8 myproject`
But it's giving me

```
Exception in thread Thread-3:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 576, in _handle_results
    task = get()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 251, in recv
    return _ForkingPickler.loads(buf.getbuffer())
  File "/home/greenbull/PycharmProjects/QazRiot/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/isort/exceptions.py", line 163, in __init__
    self._format_option(name, **option) for name, option in unsupported_settings.items()
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'items'
```

Can you help to fix this?

Comment: How is `flake8` installed? Based on the paths in the traceback, it looks like you are using a mix of libraries from your system installation and your virtual environment (though I could be mistaken about that).

Comment: If you haven't already, I would install `flake8` in your virtual environment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this is two things compounded together:

- you have `isort` set up with some unsupported option (you can probably trigger this with `isort --help`)
- isort's exceptions are not pickle safe (a bug in `isort`, [please report it there](https://github.com/PyCQA/isort))

here's a minimal reproduction as to the pickling error:

```
>>> from isort.exceptions import UnsupportedSettings
>>> import pickle
>>> e = UnsupportedSettings({'foo': {'value': 'bar', 'source': 'wat'}})
>>> e
UnsupportedSettings("isort was provided settings that it doesn't support:\n\n\t- foo = bar  (source: 'wat')\n\nFor a complete and up-to-date listing of supported settings see: https://pycqa.github.io/isort/docs/configuration/options.\n")
>>> pickle.loads(pickle.dumps(e))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/tmp/y/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/isort/exceptions.py", line 163, in __init__
    self._format_option(name, **option) for name, option in unsupported_settings.items()
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'items'
```

flake8 uses multiprocessing (and multiprocessing uses `pickle` to send arguments) for running which is why this is triggered.  you can work around this (to at least display the original error message) by running `flake8 -j1`

---

disclaimer: I'm the current flake8 maintainer